# XcodeでC++20のサンプルプログラムがコンパイルエラーになりました。

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, clang

Professional C++ Fifth EditionのDownload Sample code(C++20と思います。)がコンパイルエラーとなりました。

**実行環境:**
macOS Monteley 12.4
Xcode 13.4.1
clang 13.1.6

ネットでの情報から判断して、XcodeやClangのバージョンは、C++20を使えるのではないかと解釈しています。対策のご指導をお願いします。
`-std=c++20` を設定するとの情報がありました。これで解決するなら、具体的にどうすれば良いのかを教えてください。

(追記)
お教え頂いたように、C++Language DialectをC++20[-std=c++20]を選択して、以下のプログラム(Professional C++ 5th Editionが提供してくれたDownloardプログラム。)をBuildしたらBuild Failedとなりました。

```
import <iostream>;
 int main() 
{ 
    std::cout << "Hello, World!" << 
    std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

iostream>と;を削除してもBuild Failedとなりました。

Comment: エラーが出たなら、エラーメッセージを提示しましょう
エラーメッセージは、よけいな省略翻訳しないで出たそのママをコピペで提示してください

Comment: もしかしたらこの記事が参考になるかも。[Apple Clang 13 C++20 Module Support Missing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70168181/9014308)

Comment: 解決した場合は質問に追記するのではなく、役に立った回答にコメントするか、個別の回答として投稿してください。(質問はあくまで質問の体裁を保ってください)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ソースコードを見るに

```
#import <iostream>
```

が正解で、先頭が`#`で始まっておらず、更にその後ろの`;`が余計ですね。

`Xcode`でというタイトルから、`Xcode IDE`で`C++20`のソースをコンパイルしたいと判断しました。
まず、プロジェクトのトップをクリックし、画面右側のIDE画面で、`Build Settings`を選択します。
[image: IDE画面]
次に各項目の`Apple Clang - Language - C++`の
`C++ Language Dialect`ポップアップメニューを開き、C++20を選択します。
[image: Language Dialectの選択]

```
clang++ -std=c++20 ソースファイル -o 出力ファイル
```

でコマンドラインからコンパイルすれば行けると思います。

Comment: `CXXFLAGS` は `make` のデフォルトルールが採用している（環境）変数であって `gcc` や `clang` が直接見てはいないはず。なのでコマンドライン上で `make` するなら意味があるけど `clang++` を直接起動する際には意味がなかったはず。（時間がないので未確認）

Comment: 訂正しておきました。

Comment: お教え頂いたように、C++Language DialectをC++20[-std=c++20]を選択して、以下のプログラム(Professional C++ 5th Editionが提供してくれたDownloardプログラム。)をBuildしたらBuild Failedとなりました。import <iostream>;

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello, World!" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}

Comment: @Keita ソースやエラーは質問を編集して追記して下さい

Comment: コメントを見るに、`import <iostream>` でその後ろの`;`は要らないと思います

Comment: `import` なのか `#include` なのか、それが問題だ

Comment: 一応仕様の説明・解説はこのページあたりでしょうか。[言語機能/C++20/モジュール](https://cpprefjp.github.io/lang/cpp20/modules.html)

Comment: 言語規格書が導入した仕様であっても現実の処理系が直ちに対応しているとは限らないからなぁ。 cygwin64 では `import` を使うには `-fmodules-ts` オプションを追記しろって怒られて、追記したらしたでそんなモジュールはないよ、ってなったし。

Comment: C++仕様上は`#include <iostream>`または`import <iostream>;`が正しい構文です。が、現時点でC++20 moduleを正しく実装したコンパイラはおそらく存在しないと思います。無理に`import`構文を使う必要はないと思います。